# How do I log in to a database without username and password?

Tags: database, sql

I want to log in to a database by running a SQL file from a UNIX script without supplying username and password (as root). Any command to do so?

Comment: That depends on a few things. Can you tell us what sort of database you're using? is it on the local machine?

Comment: This question is considered abandoned, there are many sorts of databases and a lot more ways to log in to them, without more information this would be like shooting bats in the dark. I have flagged this for closure since it has no accepted answers or further activity, if you feel that this issue still affects you it is possible to contact a moderator to re-open it or if you want you can drop a comment asking to re-open it.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the username and password do use in ~/.my.cnf

```
[mysql]
user=foo
password=bar
```

But this file is unencrypted so beware of that.

Comment: that's why you chmod 700/500 this file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Many client softwares - including mysql - can get passwords from command line. Try

```
mysql -u root -pROOT_PASSWORD DATABASE_NAME
```

Where ROOT_PASSWORD is password for mysql root account. You can also use certificates for logins.

As there is some confusion, at least recent versions of mysql are masking your password from process listing. You can check this by running above mentioned command and then in another terminal

```
ps auxw | grep mysql
```

If you see something like

> mysql -u root -px xxxxx

(where `-px xxxxx` is exactly this, not your password), then your password is not viewable in process listing.

---

Security considerations:

- As @Lekensteyn mentioned in comments, beware that commands you run will be saved to history file (readable only by user and root). You can prevent this by for example unsetting `HISTFILE` variable.
- Your script should be protected with correct permissions (for example 700, which is all permissions for owner, and nothing for others).

Comment: Oh yeah, `ps aux|grep mysql`. Lovely.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: which shows "mysql -u root -px xxxxx" (where 'xxxxx' is not my password; it's masked automatically). I don't see the problem here. Lovely.

Comment: I see, did not know that, thanks. Beware for the command history, either put a space before the command or clear the `HISTFILE=` environment variable.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: good point (history file while testing), when running it from script that's not important, because commands inside script are not logged to history file.